# How to skip both the first n rows &  the last m rows simultaneously?

Tags: listings

I am using `showexpl.sty` to display side by side the code snippet and its corresponding output.

Because of the paper size limit, I intentionally want to remove the "redundant" rows, i.e., the first n rows and the last m rows from the code snippet.

Is it possible to do that in `showexpl.sty` ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset{%
% any setting goes here.
}
\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}[%
%any option goes here.
]
%redundant n rows begin
% one
% two
% ...
% n th rows
Important parts go here.
Again... it is important!
...
%redundant m rows begin
% one 
% ...
% m th rows
\end{LTXexample}

% others important parts go here.
\end{document}
```

---

I reopen this question because using `linerange` is not possible when I don't know the number of lines until at "runtime".

---

I will use @Herbert's solution for inline code inclusion and @TH's solution for external code inclusion. Unfortunately I cannot make 2 green-checked.

Comment: there is no difference in using the `linerange` argument for inline or external code. The external code can also be marked with `\START` or `%START` and same for STOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an own environment, which uses the `\START`--`\STOP` sequence of the part which should be listed. These two commands itself have no meaning. You do not need to know how many lines your code has.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\pc\@percentchar
\makeatother

\usepackage{pstricks,fancyvrb,array,listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}

\def\endExample{\end{VerbatimOut}
  \def\START{}\def\STOP{}\input{\jobname.tmp}}
\newcommand\Example{%
\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} m{0.5\linewidth}@{} 
                    >{\lstinputlisting[includerangemarker=false,
                    linerange=\\START-\\STOP]{\jobname.tmp}}m{0.5\linewidth} @{}}

\begin{Example}
\pspicture(3,2)
\START
\psframe*[linecolor=blue!30](3,2)
\STOP
\endpspicture
\end{Example}
& 
\tabularnewline

\begin{Example}
\pspicture(3,2)
\START
\psframe*[linecolor=red!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\STOP
\end{Example}
& 
\tabularnewline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your solution is faster than @TH's because iteration done by @TH needs extra time. Thank for your smart solution.

Comment: I do like this `[rangeprefix=\%,
 rangesuffix=,
 includerangemarker=false,
 linerange=start-stop]`. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can always count the number of lines in the file before hand.

```
% This line will be removed
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newread\lf
\newcount\linecount
\newcommand\linesinfile[1]{%
        \linecount0
        \openin\lf#1
        \unless\ifeof\lf
                \loop
                        \readline\lf to\lfline
                \unless\ifeof\lf
                        \advance\linecount by1
                \repeat
                \closein\lf
        \fi
}
\begin{document}
\linesinfile{\jobname.tex}
There are \number\linecount\ lines in the file `\jobname.tex'.

\small
\lstinputlisting[language={[LaTeX]TeX},firstline=2,
lastline=\numexpr\linecount-1]{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
% This line will be removed
```

Comment: How to pass the number to `linerange` ? I have more than 500 source code files.

Comment: Passing numbers to `linerange` is harder because it looks for `x-y` and when I give it `2-\numexpr\linecount-1` it doesn't like that. Instead, you can just set another count register (or just adjust `\linecount`) and use that.

Comment: I am trying to combine them into a single command.

Comment: Can `\lf` and `\linecount` be placed inside `\linesinfile` as  local variables?

Comment: @xport: `\linesinfile` is not expandable so you can't get it to just expand to the number of lines in the file. I don't really know what you mean by put it inside. You could always make a new macro `\newcommand\foo[1]{\linesinfile{#1}\lstinputlisting[firstline=n,lastline=\numexpr\linecount-m]{#1}}`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @xport: Or make `\foo` take 3 arguments and replace `n` and `m` by `#2` and `#3`.

Comment: I want all auxiliary variables to be placed inside a single command (encapsulation). I don't want too many global variables cluttering my preamble or package. :-)

Comment: @xport: LaTeX doesn't work that way. There are no local allocations.

Comment: @TH. Oh... I think TeX is an Object Oriented Language. :-)

Comment: Please wait for one more answer if any.

Comment: @xport: I don't know what that means. I'm not the one asking the question.

Comment: **In** `\newcommand\foo[3]{\linesinfile{#1}\lstinputlisting[firstline=#2+1,lastline=\numexpr\linecount-#3]{#1}}` **,** `#2+1` **DOES NOT WORK, WHY?**

Comment: @xport: use `\numexpr#2+1` instead. TeX doesn't just add numbers together.

Comment: @TH. It does not work.

Comment: @TH. Your solution is actually good and informative because I can learn from it. However, for production, your solution is slower than @Herbert's solution. Therefore, I choose his solution to be Green-checked. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: @TH. `\newcommand\foo[3]{\linesinfile{#1}\lstinputlisting[breaklines,firstline=\numexpr#2+1,lastline=\numexpr\linecount-#3]{#1}}` **does not work.**

Comment: @xport:3 things. 1. You do not need to use bold to ask questions. It looks like shouting. 2. `firstline` doesn't seem to accept numbers, but that's easy to fix: just use `\number\numexpr#2+1`. 3. I was thinking you had code in separate files already (because I didn't read the question closely enough) and didn't want to modify them. Herbert's solution writes the files out and then reads them back in. Since listings supports arbitrary linerange markers, having external files with the markers in them would be the fastest way of all. No need to write files and no need to read files twice.

Comment: @TH. Sorry for the bold faces :-). It is just for contrasting the text from the code. I have 2 scenario: one using separate files (as you thought) and the other one using inline inclusion. OK. I will review again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in a similar result in ConTeXt:

```
\typefile[range={+5,-8}]{filename}
```

will remove the first five and the last eight lines.